# How to convert date from string format in python

Tags: python, string, date

I have below table. I want to count timedelta between first and second date, second and third and so on in a for loop…
I really do not want to convert my dates in table to integer set to use timedelta() function. Is there any function in python which can convert str like: ’30.06.2019’ or 30/06/2019 to date ?
Perfect would be convert all tab[i][2] to date and then count time date between them in a loop.

```
tab = [ [21091705,  0,'30.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  653777,'29.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  653842,'29.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  641701,'28.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  642000,'27.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  0,'25.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  642030,'25.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  642030,'25.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  637030,'25.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  0,'25.06.2019'],
        [21091705,  0,'17.05.2019'],
        [21091705,  0,'25.06.2019']
        ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: do you want it in datetime format . or just changing the '.' character into '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you dont want to convert it to a table you can use this:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

dates = list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], '%d.%m.%Y'), tab))
list(np.diff(dates))

[datetime.timedelta(days=-1),
 datetime.timedelta(0),
 datetime.timedelta(days=-1),
 datetime.timedelta(days=-1),
 datetime.timedelta(days=-2),
 datetime.timedelta(0),
 datetime.timedelta(0),
 datetime.timedelta(0),
 datetime.timedelta(0),
 datetime.timedelta(days=-39),
 datetime.timedelta(days=39)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried datetime.datetime.strptime()?

So you would take a time (ex. 25.02.2019):
datetime.datetime.strptime('25.02.2019', '%d.%m.%Y')

and it reutrn s datetime format. If your date is in a different starting format, just change the '%d.%m.%Y' to be in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `strptime(string, format)` function from the `datetime` module ? Since all of your string are in the same date format, you can easily loop through them

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#datetime.datetime.strptime